# Find specific characters in byte array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am connecting to a terminal emulator using a library in android, this connects to a serial device (a switch) and shows me sent/received data.

However I am just sending byte arrays over and back so I don't know what status the switch is in, is it in enable more or configuration mode etc. This leads me to possibly enter commands in the wrong mode and they won't work. The switch is then in an unrecoverable mode as I have sent a wrong command and there is no way to delete it or get to a new line. The problem I am trying to deal with for now is the one where I don;t know the mode the switch is in. I know that I can have three different return prompts after I send a command:

```
switch>
switch#
switch(config)#
```

So I was thinking that if I read the last two characters received I could tell which mode I'm in. h>, h# and )#

I get data back in this method, whenever data is received this is run:

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data) 
{

    String str = new String(data);
    ((MyBAIsWrapper) bis).renew(data);

    mSession.write(str);
    mSession.notifyUpdate();
    viewHandler.post(updateView);
}
```

Would the best way to do this be search the byte array somehow or to convert it to a string and search the string for h>, h# and )#, then I could set a global variable depending on the value I get back? Maybe search from the end backwards?

Comment: I think, that converting it to String is the simplest and clear way. I would do so too.

Comment: When converting it to a string, don't forget to specify the encoding.

Comment: Why is it necessary to specify, I have never encoded a string, apologies for the ignorance. So i would encode it as ascii? UTF8? How do these choices affect me?

Comment: @Paul: you need to decode the bytes you get. Therefore you need to know the way they were encoded by the terminal.

Comment: well it looks like they are in decimal, as the decimal numbers on the ascii chart correspond to the numbers I am getting when I look at the letter beside it. i'm not sure what to do though. i will read about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would search the `byte[]` and avoid the overhead from the conversion to a `String`.

If it is more performant to start search from the end, depends on the data you get. I cannot judge this by the little example  you posted in your question.

If you only need to look at the last two characters:

```
if(data[data.length-2]=='h' && data[data.length-1]=='>') // "h>"


if(data[data.length-2]=='h' && data[data.length-1]=='#') // "h#"
```

Or if it is not so simple, use a loop to iterate the array.

P.s. I assumes ASCII encoding for the code above

Comment: Well I would enter a command and there could be thousands of characters returned, then a newline, then the prompt. So yes I imagine it would be the last two that would be of importance. Unless I can think of a case where they wont be the last two and I can use the loop. Your way seems reasonable. I suppose I shouldn't be converting to strings if it is easily avoided.

Comment: I checked and I am recieving numbers back, 105 27, 91 74 so i am guessing that that encoding isn't right. Seems they aren't the last two bytes so maybe a loop is best.

Comment: Only the 4 bytes? Do you know what they should mean? Interpreted as ASCII they are `i` escape `[J`.

Comment: they are just rubbish sent back after I get back switch# Seems to happen at the end of everything I get back. When I was sending the data to the terminal it doesn't show up so I did not know this stuff was being sent back. If I send the data to a text box I can see all the erroneous characters being received. So I'll have to loop from the end back to get to the h# then. In the log I see a lot of little weird boxes ['s and h's. very strange...

Comment: It seams that your terminal does not use ASCII. So you must find out what encoding / charset it uses.

Comment: Maybe this is why i am getting weird messages back, I send text like this:  String enable = "enable" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
sendOverSerial(enable.getBytes()); I am convertring a string to a byte without any encoding. This is teh terminal https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en

Comment: I think nearly every terminal emulator can use ASCII (You may need to configure it). But consider that then using ASCII you cannot transfer non ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if I can configure that, if I can't easily..I have the data as a string that I can just search for the required characters. Of course I could just use the decimal numbers I get back either, search for the relevant one. 104 and 35 I think.

Comment: `h` = 104 , `>` = 62 and `#` = 35

Comment: Thanks I'll just search for those.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean?

```
if(str.endsWith("h>") || str.endsWith("h#") || str.endsWith(")#"))
```

or simpler

```
if(str.equals("switch>") || str.equals("switch#") || str.equals("switch(context)#"))
```

or using a regex

```
final Pattern switched = Pattern.compile("switch(>|#|\\(\\w+\\)#)");

if(str.matcher(switched).matches())
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of regex etc but I need to know them separately to perform different operations, so I think it is too simple to bother with a regex and that MrSmith42's answer would suffice.